# Rename files with perl, files get deleted

Tags: perl, rename

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;
my @old_names = glob "/root/pics/*.jpg";
my $new_name = "picture$i";

foreach my $old_name (@old_names) {
    rename($old_name, $new_name) or 
        die "Couldn't rename $old_name to $new_name: $!\n";
} continue { $i++ }
```

when I execute the script it deletes the pictures, what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

This is what worked for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;
my @old_names = glob "/root/pics/*.jpg";


foreach my $old_name (@old_names) {

    my $new_name = "picture$i" . ".jpg";

    rename($old_name, "/root/pics/$new_name") or die "Couldn't rename $old_name to $new_name: $!\n";

} continue { $i++ }
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: When I do mass renames, I abort a rename when if `-e $new_name` is true. It avoids wiping out all of my files like in you did.

Comment: My next task to is compare the names of the pictures to values that are in a MySQL DB and then rename the pictures based on another column in that row. Example 010300000000149196.jpg has a USERID that is 010300000000149196 (the same as the name.) and a EMPNUM value 102. In the end i need 010300000000149196.jpg to be 102.jpg. I need to read the DB and name the picture according to the EMPNUM value. I'm completely new to PERL, so i'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: @almyz125 You need to ask a new question with the new info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
my $new_name = "picture$i";
```

Is outside your loop. Therefore it does not get updated. So all the files get renamed into the same name, which effectively deletes them.

Solution is to move the assignment inside the loop, **or** skip the variable all together and do

```
rename($old_name, "picture$i") ...
```

For golfing purposes, you might also consider

```
rename($old_name, "picture" . $i++) ...
```

You might also be interested in checking out [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy), which is a core module.

Comment: If you get a chance could you look at the comment I posted on the OP? I'm learning perl today for the first time and got thrown a project in my dept that requires it.

Comment: @almyz125 Ask a new question. One problem per question.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized `$new_name` once, outside your loop. Even though you update `$i`, you are not updating `$new_name`. Therefore every file gets renamed to `picture1` (in the current directory), and all except for the last file is lost.

Update `$new_name` inside your loop:

```
foreach my $old_name (@old_names)
{
    $new_name = "picture$i";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;
my @old_names = glob "/root/pics/*.jpg";
my $new_name = "picture$i";

foreach my $old_name (@old_names)
{
    $new_name = "picture$i";
    rename($old_name, $new_name) or die "Could not rename $old_name to $new_name: $!\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just doing in a shell (using `perl` in background):

```
rename 's/(.*).jpg/picture1_\1/' *.jpg
```